# Write Cypress tests on an intranet application protected by windows authenticaation

Tags: cypress

I'm just trying to write tests for one of the applications which is protected with windows authentication.

But I'm blocked by an error received when Cypress tries to open the application.

I can run the application on my localhost without any issues using chrome.
When I run the application it takes my windows loging infor and validated as authorized user.

However, when try to open the site using Cypress I get 401.
I suspect this is due to Cypress runner runs test under a different account( I'm guessing) which is not valid windows user account hence returns 401.

Below is the screen shot of the failure test.

[image]

Does anyone has any idea how I can fix this issue and move forward with writing my other tests?

Please do contact me if you require clarifying anything with regard to this.

Appreiciate your prompr reply in this regard.

RSF

**UPDATE:**

@soccerway, answer helped me to get it working.
Also Please visit below for more info:
https://github.com/bjowes/cypress-ntlm-auth/blob/master/README.md

Comment: can you pls confirm if your this issue or problem got sorted or not ?
because i am also stuck with same for quite some time now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please refer the following `cypress-ntlm-auth` plug-in for windows authentication. Also refer the below link;

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-ntlm-auth`

Try the following syntax:

```
cy.ntlm(ntlmHost, username, password, [domain, [workstation, [ntlmVersion]]]);
```

***note:*** 
domain, workstation, ntmlVersion are optional values. 
ntmlversion valid values are 1 or 2

Comment: Hi @soccerway, 
That helps me. But couldn't get it working on my localhost. But I was able to get it working with another host hosted on the same domain/AD.
I will look into the localhost issue.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is not very secure though. Puppeteer browsers doesn't have this issue. Wonder if cypress can follow that.  @soccerway can you advise how to use cypress ntlm without storing password like this on a test server? Our team don't have any headless account and no one would want to save their own deets on a test server.